maxmind-lite: Missing MaxMind LICENSE_KEY Command
!maxmind-lite: Missing MaxMind LICENSE_KEY Command '['/opt/psa/admin/sbin/modules/firewall/geoip/maxmind-lite', '--fetch']' returned non-zero exit status 1.!
Debian 11.9 Plesk vers. 18.06
I setup the Licence Key at the Panel.editor, but looks like not successful
````LICENSE_KEY ="xxxxxxxx" plesk sbin modules/firewall/ipsets --configure --data-source maxmind-lite --force`

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
